# Malformed XML error while creating the S3 life cycle policy using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, s3-lifecycle-policy

I am trying to add a lifecycle rule to a s3 bucket using boto3. But got stuck with following error **"Error on adding lifecycle An error occurred (MalformedXML)
when calling the PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema"**.
Any idea why I am getting this error?

Here is the rule which i am trying to create

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket_lifecycle_configuration = s3.BucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucket_name)
date = date.today()


response = bucket_lifecycle_configuration.put(
                LifecycleConfiguration={
                    'Rules': [
                        {
                            'Expiration': {
                                'Date': datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day),
                                 
                                'ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker': True
       
                                
                            },
                            'ID': 'Move unused bucket to Glacier',
                            'Prefix': '',
                            'Status': 'Enabled',
                            'Transitions': [
                                {
                                    'Date': datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day),
                                    'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'
                                }
                            ],
                            'NoncurrentVersionTransitions': [
                                {
                                    'NoncurrentDays': 123,
                                    'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'
                                }
                            ],
                            'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {
                                'NoncurrentDays': 123
                            },
                            'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {
                                'DaysAfterInitiation': 123
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker` flag cannot be used with `Dates` or `Days`. thats the cause of the `MalformedXML` exception. it is explained in the attached reference.

Also note `NoncurrentVersionExpiration` date cannot be same as `NoncurrentVersionTransitions` date. The expiration date should be after the transition date.

Reference:
[put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration)

Comment: Thanks it worked after removing the ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker